# How to stop Hue from changing Image Border Color Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently making a program that allows you to change image properties at will. Whenever I change the image hue it will also change the image border color (if there is one). Is there any way to avoid this and keep the border color to what it was set to? I haven't really tried anything since there's nothing on the internet and I have no idea how I could fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap your image in a container of the same size. Apply filters to elements inside this container, and set the border on the container.

```css
.container {
  border: 16px solid red;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}

.container img {
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/888/256/256">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is I'm using javascript/html to set the values of the border color, width, image height, width etc.. So I can't just set it to a value at the beginning without knowing what the input will be. How am I capable of transferring that data to my CSS file or doing something that can replicate that?

Comment: @Cyrillic All of the values in my question can be changed through JavaScript, e.g. `document.documentQuerySelector('.container > img').style.filter = 'hue-rotate(45deg)'`. Changing any of these values will keep the border intact

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. I uploaded my image, set image height and width to 256 pixels and when I processed the image there was no hue rotate filter active. I also tried using `document.QuerySelector('.container > img').style.borderColor = varBorderColor;` (i moved everything to `.container img {}` since all the data was in the <img> part anyways) to change the border color and that seemed to just remove the border and it was still affected by hue.